# Graphing $E_p = E_k + E_{rot}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, experimental-physics, energy-conservation, moment-of-inertia

I am measuring the moment of inertia of a flywheel and using conservation of energy to work out the value (I am ignoring friction).

So for the experiment I have to roll the flywheel down a slope (I have done this by putting the flywheel's axles on rails with the rest of the flywheel having no contact with anything). I then vary the height of the track with a scissor lift (with the flywheel always starting roughly in the same place but at a different height). I then have a light gate just before the end of the track to measure the time taken to pass through the gate. This can be used to work out the final velocity of the flywheel. I have to measure the height of the flywheel after the height of the track has been adjusted (h), the mass of the flywheel (m) and the final velocity of the flywheel (v) to graph using conservation of energy.

I want to graph $E_p=E_k + E_{rot}$ in such a way that the gradient will give me the moment of inertia of the flywheel so for this I change the equation into \begin{equation}
 mgh = 1/2mv² + 1/2Iω² \end{equation}

I then times it by two to get rid of the 1/2 to get: \begin{equation}
 2mgh = mv² + I\omega² \end{equation}

I get the h on its own to get: \begin{equation}
 h = \frac{v^2}{2g} + \frac{I\omega²}{2mg} \end{equation}

I switch the second and third term around along with move the omega² next to the fraction (this is just to get it in similar form to y = ax + c):
\begin{equation}
 h = \frac{I}{2mg} (\omega^2) + \frac{v^2}{2g}  \end{equation}

Once I have done that I plot the height of the flywheel up the y-axis and the angular velocity squared (which can be worked since I know the final velocity of the flywheel and radius of the axles of the flywheel) of the flywheel along the x-axis. Once all the data has been graphed I can work out the gradient (a) and then rearrange \begin{equation}a=\frac{I}{2mg} \end{equation} to get I (the moment of inertia). So this should all work out fine but I unsure if  \begin{equation} \frac{v^2}{2g}  \end{equation}
has any physically meaning or not?

Comment: What are the coordinates of your plot?

Comment: You really need to explain better how you're measuring $I$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without slippage:

$$v=\frac{2\pi R}{T},$$ With $R$ radius of the flywheel and $T$ period of revolution. Also $\omega=\frac{2\pi}{T}$, so:

$$v=\omega R.$$.

Thus $v$ and $\omega$ aren't independent and either one of your choice can be eliminated from your formula. As $v$ is easier to measure, so use $\omega=\frac{v}{R}$ to eliminate $\omega$.

So $\frac{v^2}{2g}$ is not some 'intercept'.

Your first formula then becomes:

$\large{mgh = \frac{mv^2}{2} + \frac{Iv^2}{2R^2}}.$